# How to include or in a for loop python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying my first little web scraping attempts with python and I have come across the following problem:

```
for resultat in tr.find_all(class_='tc fs-17 white bg-darkgrey p-r' or class_='tc fs-9 white bg-red mb-2 lh-data'):
    data.append(resultat.text)
```

I need to ensure on the for loop that either the class_ is data is appended to the data. however, I have no clue how to do it.

A little help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: @goodvibration is right you need to share your code snippet too.

Comment: But my for stament is included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, you can separate the loop.

```
for resultat in tr.find_all(class_='tc fs-17 white bg-darkgrey p-r'):
    data.append(resultat.text)
for resultat in tr.find_all(class_='tc fs-9 white bg-red mb-2 lh-data'):
    data.append(resultat.text)
```

Comment: Great to know. Make a upvote to the ans if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use one loop, you can firstly use the [`.extend` method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_extend.asp#:%7E:text=Python%20List%20extend%20()%20Method%201%20Definition%20and,iterable%20(list,%20set,%20tuple,%20etc.)%204%20More%20Examples) to append one list to another.

```py
background_darkgrey = tr.find_all(class_='tc fs-17 white bg-darkgrey p-r')
background_red = tr.find_all(class_='tc fs-9 white bg-red mb-2 lh-data')
elements_to_scrape = background_darkgrey.extend(background_red)
```

And after it, just iterate over `elements_to_scrape`.

```py
for resultat in elements_to_scrape:
    data.append(resultat.text)
```